# "Could not load credentials from any providers" while using dynamodb locally in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

im setting up a dynamodb locally to test with my Node app. To set it up i just plain out copied the code from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.01.html) and adjusted it for my needs. 
This is the code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var config = ({
  "apiVersion": "2012-08-10",
  "accessKeyId": "abcde",
  "secretAccessKey": "abcde",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "endpoint": "http://localhost:8001",
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB(config);

var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

This throws an error though and i have no idea why:

```
Unable to create table. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Missing credentials in config",
  "code": "CredentialsError",
  "time": "2017-04-10T11:45:26.748Z",
  "retryable": true,
  "originalError": {
    "message": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
    "code": "CredentialsError",
    "time": "2017-04-10T11:45:26.747Z",
    "retryable": true,
    "originalError": {
      "message": "Connection timed out after 1000ms",
      "code": "TimeoutError",
      "time": "2017-04-10T11:45:26.747Z",
      "retryable": true
    }
  }
}
```

Would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently i figured out the problem. Using a json file to set the credentials still led to the error. Using only the config object without the flag -inMemory caused an error too. The combination of hard coding the credentials in the script and using the -inMemory flag while starting the dynamodb locally seemed to solve this. I really don't understand why though.

Answer (score 77):

I had the same error. In my case the issue was that it worked fine locally running from the command line, but not in docker.

Basically how to pass credentials to AWS npm S3 client between `aws-sdk`  (version 2) and `@aws-sdk/s3-client` (version 3), has changed. In v2 case, the structure is like that:

```
const credentials = {
    region: configuration.aws.region,
    accessKeyId: configuration.aws.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: configuration.aws.secretAccessKey
};
```

In v3:

```
const credentials = {
  region: configuration.aws.region,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: configuration.aws.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: configuration.aws.secretAccessKey
  }
};
```

It was working locally fine because I was already authenticated to AWS through CLI and it was ignoring those v2 style credentials that I passed to v3 client.

Conclusion: use typescript for everything boys & girls!

Comment: This one worked for me!

Comment: Thanks! aws-sdk docs does mention this but just not clear enough

Answer (score 15):

Change to the following code, have dummy `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`, then run it

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-1',
  accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
  secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
  endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8000'),
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer is for V2.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

```
const sqsClient = new SQSClient({ 
      region: REGION,
      credentials: {
         accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

As per error message your credentials is not set in `config`.

I am giving my view to set the credentials and then use the services.

```
 const aws = require('aws-sdk');
 aws.config = new aws.Config();
 aws.config.accessKeyId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 aws.config.secretAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";
 aws.config.region = "region";
```

Now then use the Dynamodb

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```

***UPDATE***

you ca also set credential with file

```
aws.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json');
```

Hope it works!!

Comment: You are using windows machine and have you installed aws-cli?

Comment: any how it's setting null values that's why it's coming? is there any env variable is set for aws?
I am updating my answer with add credentials with file.

Comment: i've moved the credentials outside of the script and into a json file. This still gives me the error and i really don't know why.

Comment: You need to dig yourself, some how it set null, it's not using the configuration which you have given in code

Comment: i dont create a dynamodb object anywhere else in the code. As i stated above this is literally the code amazon provides as a tutorial which is not working. Java runtime is up to date, the credentials json is in the same folder and i dont change the values anyhwere. I really can't figure out this problem.

Comment: what is the structure of the json file? Aws is honestly the worst documentation of all times

Comment: You can refer this for example https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137780/loading-credentials-json-with-aws-sdk-results-in-error

Answer (score 3):

In node.js, you can easily load from `.env` value by setting these values

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

AWS_SESSION_TOKEN (Optional)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html

Answer (score 2):

Another option/solution to this problem would be creating a `credentials` file at your user's home.

Something like:

`~/.aws/credentials`

And the content will be:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = *************************
aws_secret_access_key = *********************************************
aws_session_token =**************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably are confusing between web service DynamoDB and local version. You can find the main differences between both in [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/dynamolocal-vs-dynamoservice.html).

If you want to use a local version of DynamoDB, you will find the latest informations to install and run it in [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Download.html).

Once you're done, make sure to run the local DynamoDB instance by running:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory
```

Your error will probably be avoided.

Comment: i was running dynamodb locally the whole time, which is the reason i set port 8001. i hoped the inMemory flag you provided might not lead to this error but it does. Sadly your solution does not help.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB local works fine for me on **port 8000** with dummy credentials.

**Note:**

The port number is **8000**. I use the below dummy credentials.

```
var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials: creds
});
```

**Start command:-**

```
java -Djava.library.path=DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

**OS:-**

Windows

Comment: thanks for your input. I figured it out eventually though and answered it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v3 aws-sdk and want to create a session and load your config in programmatically, here's how to do so with the [@aws-sdk/credential-providers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/credential-providers) module.

### Methods to set your AWS Secrets:

1. `aws sso configure`

- Run the `aws sso configure` command. This will prompt you to enter some account specific information.
- After you're authenticated and setup, verify the new profile was created via the `~/.aws/config` file.
- You'll see something like this:

  ```
  [profile abc-123123123]
  sso_session = test
  sso_account_id = 123123123
  sso_role_name = hello
  region = us-west-2
  output = json

  [sso-session test]
  sso_start_url = https://aws.com
  sso_region = us-west-2
  ```
- Login to this profile with this command `aws sso login --profile abc-123123123`

2. Use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module

- In the root of your source code or script, import the `dotenv` module to pull in any `.env` secrets to your current `process`
- Copy and paste the AWS secrets into your `.env` file:

  ```
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="abc123"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="abc123"
  AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="abc123"
  ```

3. Copy the AWS secrets and save to `~/.aws/credentials`

- Copy the same secrets as in step 2, but instead of saving to your `.env` file, save to your `~/.aws/credentials` file in the same format

### Fetching and using the credentials

Install the [@aws-sdk/credential-providers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/credential-providers) module

If you've configured a `Profile` in your `~/.aws/config` file:

```js
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { fromIni } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: fromIni({ profile: 'abc-123123123' })
});
```

If you've setup the `~/.aws/credentials` file:

```js
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { fromIni } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: fromIni({ filepath: "~/.aws/credentials" })
});
```

See the [fromIni](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/packages/credential-providers#fromini) docs for more config options available.